# Changing Image onclick with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image, onclick, src

Hey i want to change a image when the img is clicked with javascript it works once if i click the picture it changes the scr but doesnt change it back

```js
function ImgClick() {
  var img = document.getElementById("b1")
  if (img.src = "img/RoteAmpel.jpg") {
    img.src = "img/GrueneAmpel.jpg";
  } else {
    img.src = "img/RoteAmpel.jpg";
  }


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Mouse Events</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">

</head>

<body>
  <h3>Mouse Events</h3>
  <img src="img/RoteAmpel.jpg" alt="Bildwechsel" title="Bildwechsel" id="b1" onclick="ImgClick()" />


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: if(img.src="img/RoteAmpel.jpg") <---- assignment, not comparison.

Comment: so i gotta do == ? when i write if(img.src=="img/RoteAmpel.jpg") it doesnt even change it once

Comment: And most developers tend to use `===` instead, to avoid unexpected behavior when comparing values of different types

Comment: `console.log(img.src, img.src == "img/RoteAmpel.jpg")` is it what you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems with your code:

#### 1. Assignment vs Comparison

You're assigning the `src` instead of making a comparison:

```
if (img.src="img/RoteAmpel.jpg") { }
```

should be

```
if (img.src === "img/RoteAmpel.jpg") { }
```

#### 2. `img.src` might not be what you expect

When accessing `img.src` you'll get the full qualified URL including protocol, domain etc.

To compare the actually attribute's value use this:

```
img.getAttribute('src')
```

You can test it yourself:

```js
function test() {
  var img = document.getElementById("b1")
      
  console.log(img.src);
  console.log(img.getAttribute('src'));
 }
    
test();
```

```html
<img id="b1" src="img/RoteAmpel.jpg">
```

Comment: Yes thanks for the help you didnt only help me to fix it i also understood what was wrong because of the function test you gave me thank you :)